# error crashlytics firebase after renameField

Tags: java, android, kotlin, migration, realm

Error : `in realm, io.realm.RealmObjectSchema.checkFieldExists: Field name doesn't exist on object "ModelName": "oldField"`
After renameField I get this error in firebase, but somehow when I build and running from android studio My Apps running well there is no problem. I try to reproduce this error. But It didn't work. I don't see any problems in the code

This my code in migration.kt:

```
if (oldVersion == 11L) {
schema.get("ModelName")!!
   .renameField("oldField", "newField")
   oldVersion++
}
```

and also I have increased the Migration schema

Answer (score 0):

if you want to migrate from realm, dynamicRealm is designed to open Realm file without checking schemas.

To delete version 0 Realm file, you can do something like this:

```
File file = new File(realmConfig.getPath());
 if (file.exist()) {
 DynamicRealm dynamicRealm = DynamicRealm.getInstance(realmConfig);
 long version = dynamicRealm.getVersion();
 dynamicRealm.close();
 if (version == 0) {
    Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfig);
}
```

}